# Building a RAID 6 NVMe SSD only server using Supermicro case, backplane, and mobo with a Broadcom MegaRAID 9670-24i

Tags: raid, nvme, broadcom, supermicro

***To summarize**: It will be a bummer to ship all these parts then fly out to do the build to find out a $2,000 RAID card doesn't play nice with a backplane. or that i bought the wrong cable since the backplane says "SlimSAS x8" ports and the card says "x8 SFF-8654" ports.
It would also be helpful if there was any constructive criticism incase I'm overlooking something.*

---

I need a bit of help. I am putting together a new machine for a client of mine. I would like the extra speed of NVMe drives and I want to have the redundancy of RAID 6. This leaves 6 drive slots open for future expansion with another raid card to run them. The initial build only needs one raid card and 6 drives.

- I'm thinking this case: https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/chassis/2u/la26/scla26ac12-r1k23aw
- It uses this backplane: https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/BPN-SAS3-LA26A-N12.pdf
- This mobo: https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/X12DDW-A6
- This RAID card: https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-9670-24i
- And these drives: https://www.samsung.com/us/business/computing/memory-storage/enterprise-solid-state-drives/pm9a3-nvme-u-2-ssd-7-6tb-mz-ql27t600/

Initially there will be a 6 drive RAID 6 array which should use up all 3 ports on the Broadcom card. When this fills up we will get another card and another 6 drives. The backplane combines 2 NVMe drives into a single SlimSAS x8.

**The question**: Will this combo of parts work? I think it will but Broadcom support has gotten word from Supermicro that it may not be compatible. Has anyone used one of these Broadcom cards with a Supermicro NVMe backplane with NVMe drives? (as much as I can tell the 1U backplane that supports 10 NVMe drives should be wired similarly to this 12 drive backplane)

Any experiences with this setup or possible compatibility issues would be great. The fall back plan is [using this](https://www.samsung.com/us/business/computing/memory-storage/enterprise-solid-state-drives/pm893-2-5-sata-7-68tb-mz-7l37t600/); those with an expander backplane and a RAID card. But I would like the extra speed of the NVMe and I know shoving 6 NVMe drives through a RAID card will throttle them but it will still be much faster than a SATA bus. not to mention the theoretical maximum of 6 of those samsung drives is 40.2GBps and pcie 4.0 can handle 32GBps unidirectionally and those are theoretical maximums if all the data is perfectly laid out and assuming 0 delays from the raid 6 calculations. Writing from the array has a max theoretical throughput of just 24GBps which is below what the PCIe 4 bus can handle. In short, I don’t think there is going to be much of a speed bottle neck here beyond what the raid card does.

I have looked into compatibility and am coming up with nothing Broadcom has told me they put in a ticket about compatibility with Supermicro and got back a response saying its not compatible but I know in the past I have talked with SuperMicro and they say that said that about things that simply have not been tested in their lab.

---

**Edit**: I removed the question about if the PCIe risers are included with the motherboard or not and what cable is needed between the RAID card and backplane. I will repost those somewhere else.

Comment: One question per post please. Also, you're asking a random internet site for specifications of hardware sold by someone else, and that sort of question is off topic on this site.

Comment: @music2myear then where should it get posted because im getting mum and conflicting things from the manufacturer and figured someone outside of their respective bubbles would have some experience hooking these up ... and no problem i can get rid of what cable to connect the raid card to the backplane and if the case comes with the risers or not

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for the [Hardware Recommendations SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 cool i will post it there

Comment: @CcDd You should really post this stuff on [Hardware Recommendations SE](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from Supermicro so not compatible.

> Thank you for contacting Supermicro technical support, unfortunately we do not test and validate third part RAID controllers, for NVMe RAID this controller will not work is not compatible with our backplanes.
>
> For NVMe RAID we only support VROC key module :
>
> https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/accessories/addon/AOC-VROCxxxMOD.php